# Cannot create a generic array

Tags: java, generics

I'm getting the error "Cannot create a generic array" for the following code:

```
public class MapImpl<K, V> {
    private static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;

    private int size;
    // array holding the entries of the map
    private Entry[] entries;

    public MapImpl() {
        entries = new Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY]; // error at this line: Cannot create a generic array of MapImpl<K,V>.Entry
    }

    // represents an entry in the map
    private class Entry {
        private K key;
        private V value;

        public Entry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
```

Surprisingly, this works fine:

```
public class MapImpl<K, V> {
    private static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;

    private int size;
    // array holding the entries of the map
    private Entry<K, V>[] entries;

    public MapImpl() {
        entries = new Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
    }

    // represents an entry in the map
    private class Entry<K, V> {
        private K key;
        private V value;
//but here K and V are being hidden.
        public Entry(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    }
```

> I do understand that we can't create an array of generic type or a
>   type that takes type parameters. But, here in my code the Entry class
>   is not of a generic type. Am i overlooking something ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529085/how-to-create-a-generic-array-in-java

Comment: @Parth I don't think so. I already know that question. My context is different.

Comment: Is there a reason you've made `Entry` an inner class? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70324/java-inner-class-and-static-nested-class.

Comment: @Radiodef There is no specific reason; it's just some trivial code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem here is that non-static nested class has access to all members of its outer classes, which includes information about generic types used in outer class, like

```
class Outer<T>{
    private T t;
    class Inner{
        void method(T tt){//we can use same type T as used in outer class
            t = tt;
        }
    }
}
```

So in reality `Inner` class type is more like `Outer<T>.Inner` which makes form of it generic type and arrays can't be created from generic types because of type erasure which would prevent arrays from being able to test if added elements are valid.

Most common solution in that cases is to use collections instead of arrays like `List<OurType>`.

But if you really want to have only arrays then other possible solution (but you should try to avoid it) is to use raw type, so instead of

```
new Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
```

which is equivalent of

```
new MapImpl<K, V>.Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
```

you could use

```
new MapImpl.Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
//         ^no generic type -> it is raw type
```

---

Solution with

```
private class Entry<K, V> {
    private K key;
    private V value;
//but here K and V are being hidden.
    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

works ***probably*** (I can't find any relevant JLS describing this) because as you said, you have shadowed original `K` and `V` from outer class, which means you can't access them and now

```
        void method(T tt){
            t = tt;
        }
```

method will not compile because `T` from inner class is not the same as `T` from outer class. Because of that, `Entry` is no longer `MapImpl<K,V>.Entry` but `MapImpl.Entry<K,V>` and when you write it as

```
new Entry[...]
```

you are explicitly making it raw type which will work (with compilation warning about rawtypes when you declare `private Entry[] entries`)

Comment: Thanks for reading my question carefully and giving the perfect explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `Entry` class as static. Currently it's not static, so it's implicitly linked to the MapImpl instance and to its generic arguments.

Edit: I mean

```
 private static class Entry<K, V>
```

Comment: It does not help. In this case OP will have to make it generic implicitly.

Comment: @Tagir Valeev, not really. In that case I can't make a reference of K and V in Entry class.

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: In that case , the type parameters K&V of Entry class hides that of MapImpls's K&V, which probably is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since `Entry` is an inner class of a generic class `MapImpl`, it is also parametrized by `K` and `V`.  To make an array, you will have to create it with raw type:

```
entries = new MapImpl.Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. May I know the difference between new Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY] and new MapImpl.Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY] ?

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, by declaring `Entry` as an inner class of `MapImpl`, you are tying `Entry` to an instance of `MapImpl`.  That makes `Entry` generic by `MapImpl`'s parametric types.  The full name of class `Entry` is `MapImpl<K,V>.Entry`.  By creating array of `MapImpl.Entry`, you make the type raw rather then generic.

Answer (score 0):

It's because Java's arrays (unlike generics) contain, at runtime, information about its component type. So you must know the component type when you create the array. Since you don't know what `K` and `V` are at runtime, you can't create the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code instead

```
package com.vibhs.stack.overflow.generics;

public class MapImpl<K, V> {
private static int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 16;

private int size;
// array holding the entries of the map
private Entry[] entries;

public MapImpl() {
    entries = new Entry[DEFAULT_CAPACITY]; // error at this line: Cannot
                                            // create a generic array of
                                            // MapImpl<K,V>.Entry
}

// represents an entry in the map
private class Entry<K,V> {
    private K key;
    private V value;

    public Entry(K key, V value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know that it works.I just edited my post. But i want to know the reason behind it.